# Unified assembly language

Tags: performance, assembly, bytecode, opcode, multiplatform

I wonder if there exists some kind of universal and easy-to-code opcode (or assembly) language which provides basic set of instructions available in most of today's CPUs (not some fancy CISC, register-only computer, just common one). With possibility to "compile", micro-optimize and "interpret" on any mentioned CPUs?

I'm thinking about something like MARS MIPS simulator (rather simple and easy to read code), with possibility to make real programs. No libraries necessary (but nice thing if that possible), just to make things (libraries or UNIX-like tools) faster in uniform way.

Sorry if that's silly question, I'm new to assembler. I just don't find NASM or UNIX assembly language neither extremely cross-platform nor easy to read and code.

Comment: What is the application you have a mind?

Comment: Well there are people joking that `C` is just portable assembler. And since it is quite often used as target language of compilers there might be some truth in it.

Comment: jmh: Well, C mostly stood still since mid seventies (bar some minor standarization work), and assemblers are more advanced nowadays :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM bytecode is sort of like assembly language, but without pointer arithmetic. However, it's quite object-oriented. On the positive side, it's totally cross-platform.

You might want to look at LLVM bytecode - but bear in mind this warning: http://llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#can-i-compile-c-or-c-code-to-platform-independent-llvm-bitcode

Comment: I agree with LLVM recommendation :)

Answer (score 4):

First thing: writing in Assembly does not guarantee a speed increase. Using the correct algorithm for the job at hand has the greatest impact on speed. By the time you need to go down to Assembly to squeeze the last few drops out you can only really do that by adapting the algorithm to the specific architecture of the hardware in question. A generic HLA (High Level Assembler) pretty much defeats the purpose of writing your code in Assembly. Note that I am not knocking [Randall Hyde’s](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/index.html) [HLA](http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/index.html), which is a great product, I’m just saying that you don’t gain anything from writing Assembly the way a compiler generates machine code. Most C and C++ compilers have very good optimizers, and can produce machine code superior to almost any naïve implementation in ASM.

See if you can find these books (2nd hand, they are out of print) by Michael Abrash: "Zen of Assembly Language", and "Zen of Code Optimization". Or look if you can find his articles on DDJ. They will give you an insight into optimization second to none,

Comment: It would be nice if the people who downvoted my answer would leave a comment explaining why they think my answer was unhelpful. The questioner implied that writing in ASM will "make things faster in uniform way", this is just not true. If you want to code faster; go high level. If you want faster code, improve your algorithm. The only "magic" to (native) ASM is the ability to be more specific about what you want the CPU to do. You lose most of that with a UASM (which is high noise, low signal; for little better [often worse] results than a compiled high level language).

Answer (score 2):

Related stuff, so I hope might be useful :

There is

- [flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net/)

with an approach of a kind of portable assembler.

Interesting project of operating system with graphical user interface written in assembler, and great assembly API :

- [Menuet OS](http://www.menuetos.net/)

Comment: the OP asked about unified assembly **language**, not assembler

Comment: That's why I've wrote "Related stuff, so I hope might be useful" , by "related" I've meant that it does not necessarily answer question directly, but as IMHO closely related might be helpful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

[LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) provides quite portable assembly, backed with powerful [compiler, backing many projects including Clang](http://llvm.org)